# Recursive MySQL Query for Variable Overlaps

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I am trying to figure out how to do a recursive query in MySQL.

I have a table where I am tracking the dates someone had a certification. It is possible for the same certification to overlap -- say you get recertified before the end to keep your certification up!

Here is an example of the table that is tracking the user certifications. The `user` and `cert` tables are pretty basic and unnecessary for the question.

```
CREATE TABLE user_cert (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user INT NOT NULL,
    cert INT NOT NULL,
    date_begin DATE NOT NULL,
    date_end DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

For example, for one user, this might be the values.

```
| id | user | cert | date_begin | date_end   |
|----|------|------|------------|------------|
| 01 | 100  | 1000 | 2018-12-01 | 2019-02-01 |
| 02 | 100  | 1000 | 2019-04-01 | 2019-07-01 |
| 03 | 100  | 1000 | 2019-06-01 | 2019-09-01 |
| 04 | 100  | 1000 | 2019-08-01 | 2019-12-01 |
| 05 | 100  | 1000 | 2019-07-01 | 2019-11-01 |
```

Here is a visual representation. The `○` represent the start and end dates of each certification period. The `●` represent the start and end date I am looking to get in a query. There could be any number of overlaps. The `|` represents the date I am checking.

```
id--12--01--02--03--04--05--06--07--08--09--10--11--12--
01  ○-------○                 | 
02                  ●-----------○
03                          ○-----------○
04                            |     ○---------------●
05                            | ○---------------○
```

It is simple to write a query to get the minimum date and the maximum date for the the rows that overlap the date I am checking (`2019-06-15`).

```
SELECT user, MIN(date_begin), MAX(date_end)
FROM user_cert
WHERE user = 100 AND '2019-06-15' BETWEEN date_begin AND date_end
GROUP BY user;
```

This would yield `1, '2019-04-01', '2019-09-01'` because of the two rows that overlap.

My question is this: is it possible to get `1, '2019-04-01', '2019-12-01'` out of a single query to get the minimum and maximum dates of continuous certification? I know how to do it if I were to join in the `user_cert` table many times, but that would only allow so many layers of expansion. What if I do not know how many possible extending overlaps exist?

Comment: So, a gaps and islands problem

Comment: This is similar to how a bookings availability system would work. It is a lot easier to track availability if your start and end dates are stored as separate records in the DB as a start event and an end event, with a modifier value against each -- ie +1 for the starts and -1 for the ends. Then you can simply query them in date order and run through them adding/subtracting the value and keeping an eye on the total. Any time it goes to zero you know you've hit an uncovered date range which lasts until the next record which should bring it back up to +1 again.

Comment: Note that there is no user 1 here

Comment: @Strawberry Updating that now, oversight.

Comment: You have not said so, should we assume you are using MySQL 8.0, which supports recursive queries?

Comment: So, to answer your question: no, it's not possible to get `1, '2019-04-01', '2019-12-01'` from this data set

Comment: No, it is on 5.6 (or something similar). :(

Answer (score 0):

For mysql 8.0, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_cert (
    `user` int not null,
    date_begin date not null,
    date_end date not null
);
INSERT user_cert(`user`,date_begin,date_end)
VALUES (100,'2018-12-01','2019-02-01')
,(100,'2019-04-01','2019-07-01')
,(100,'2019-06-01','2019-09-01')
,(100,'2019-08-01','2019-12-01')
,(100,'2019-07-01','2019-11-01')
,(101,'2019-04-01','2019-07-01')
,(101,'2019-06-01','2019-09-01')
,(101,'2019-08-01','2019-12-01')
,(101,'2019-01-01','2019-03-01');

;WITH RECURSIVE cte_r(`user`,date_begin,date_end,rid)
AS
(
  SELECT `user`, date_begin, date_end, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `user` ORDER BY date_begin) AS rid
  FROM user_cert 
),
cte_range(`user`,date_begin, date_end, rid)
AS
(
  SELECT `user`,date_begin, date_end, rid
  FROM cte_r
  WHERE rid=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p.`user`, CASE WHEN c.date_begin<p.date_end THEN p.date_begin ELSE c.date_begin END AS date_begin, 
    c.date_end,c.rid
  FROM cte_range p
  INNER JOIN cte_r c
  ON p.`user`=c.`user`
  AND p.rid+1=c.rid
 )
 SELECT `user`,date_begin,MAX(date_end) AS date_end FROM Cte_range GROUP BY `user`,date_begin;
```

Comment: Let me find an installation that supports this and I will give it a go!